# How do I make my navbar only a gradiented shadow

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a navbar with a gradiented background as shown in the image below

[How can I create the gradient in the red box in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPEBm.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample CSS class for using gradients.

```
#gradient {
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient( black, white);
}
```

You can tweak the opacity for shadows accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
div {
     background-image: linear-gradient(black, white);
     height:60px;
     position:fixed;
     top:0px;
     width:100%;
     border:2px solid black;
     text-align:center;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```css
div {
     background-image: linear-gradient(grey, white);
     height:60px;
     position:fixed;
     top:0px;
     width:100%;
     border:2px solid black;
     text-align:center;
   }
```

```html
<div><h1>My Youtube Channel</h1></div>
```

A completely working example!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `linear-gradient`.

`background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);`

This is rgba black full opacity (1) to rgba black 0 opacity. If you want it to be lighter you can set the first rgba to something like `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`, black half opacity (0.5).